# update native google maps app from a web app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-maps-api-3, web-applications

Can I have a web app running, and a native google maps app launched by the web app running on a droid, and have actions performed by the user on the web app automatically update the native map app?

Ex. User clicks link on web app. Query string values in the address feed maker points to the maps app and it launches in the native app rather than a browser if the user chooses that. Then, user goes back to web app, makes changes. When user goes to map app, changes on web app are already reflected in map app via some sort of push notification system from the web app to the native map app.

Is this at all possible to do?

Comment: `too much description. woohhhhhhh`

Comment: Sorry about that. Can I have a web app running, and a native google maps app running on a droid, and have actions performed by the user on the web app automatically update the native map app?

Comment: That's what I initially thought, but if I go back to someone else who asked me about this and I say it can't be done, I'm going to have to do a lot of explaining as to why, because "can't be done" is almost always an unacceptable answer where I work. But let me see if anyone else has heard of such a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are talking about web app runs on the same devices, you can at least use some [URL scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme) to open the native Maps app. But there seems to have no way for returning the information back to your web app. (well, for the sign-in app, there seems to be some connection and data sharing between the signed in devices, but not sure how it works.)

but the ultimate solution I can think of to this question is to develop your own version of the Maps app, which should be an app that use Google Maps API to do basically the same thing the google maps does, which also sync data with your backend web server.

Comment: I think you're right, and I suspected the same thing. However I actually don't need the web app to receive anything from the native map app, but vice versa. So when someone adds an address via the UI in the web app, I would like to send a push to the map app running it's directions in the background so that it will now add this to what it is already giving directions to. Sounds far fetched to me, but I have to check before I give that answer.